# How to cut python output in rows and columns

Tags: python, string, awk

Hi All i have written below program to take output of linux process

```
import subprocess
def backupOperation():
   p = subprocess.Popen(["ls","-la"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   output, err = p.communicate()
   print(output)

 backupOperation()
```

if i print output its output is as shown below

```
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  100 Dec 29  2013 .cshrc
 drwx------.  3 root root   24 Dec 21 15:14 .dbus
 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    6 Dec 21 15:21 Desktop
 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    6 Dec 21 15:21 Documents
 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    6 Dec 21 15:21 Down loads
 drwx------.  2 root root   22 Dec 21 17:07 .elinks
 -rw-------.  1 root root   16 Dec 21 15:21 .esd_auth
 drwx------.  2 root root   79 Dec 21 16:42 .gnupg
 -rw-------.  1 root root 1240 Feb 21 20:19 .ICEauthority
 -rw-r--r--.  1 root root 1142 Dec 21 15:15 initial-setup-ks.cfg
 drwx------.  3 root root   18 Dec 21 15:21 .local
 drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root   37 Dec 21 16:53 .mozilla
 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    6 Dec 21 15:21 Music
 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    6 Dec 21 15:21 Pictures
 drwxr-----.  3 root root   18 Dec 21 15:49 .pki
 -rw-r--r--   1 root root  172 Feb 24 22:44 process.py
 -rw-------.  1 root root   10 Dec 21 17:48 .psql_history
 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    6 Dec 21 15:21 Public
 -rw-------.  1 root root 1024 Dec 21 16:43 .rnd
 drwx------   2 root root   24 Feb 22 00:12 .ssh
 drwx------.  3 root root 4096 Dec 21 16:44 ssl-build
 -rw-r--r--.  1 root root  129 Dec 29  2013 .tcshrc
 drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    6 Dec 21 15:21 Templates
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    6 Dec 21 15:21 Videos
-rw-------   1 root root 6994 Feb 24 22:44 .viminfo
```

all i want is to cut first column of the out put as i do using awk like awk '{print $1}'
Here i want to do this using python but i do not find any suitable string function doing this.Can this be achieved using python or i have to use shell for such operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def backupOperation():
   p = subprocess.Popen(["ls","-la"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
   output, err = p.communicate()
   print("\n".join([ x.split(None,1)[0] for x in output.splitlines()]))
```

Or actually use `awk` piping the output to it:

```
def backupOperation():
   p = subprocess.Popen(["ls","-la"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
   p2 = subprocess.Popen(["awk", '{print $1}'], stdin=p.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
   p.stdout.close()  
   out,err = p2.communicate()
   print("".join(out))

drwxrwxr-x
drwxrwxr-x
-rw-rw-r--
.......
```

Comment: What does not running mean exactly?

Comment: o i didnt know you could use None for the first argument of split ... thats cool :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley, yep, then you can have  arbitrary amounts of whitespace.

Comment: @Padraic verymuch thanks for the solution above ans needs one more modification  as p2 = subprocess.Popen 

i have used awk solution .Can you please also explain how is 
print("\n".join([ x.split(None,1)[0] for x in output.splitlines()])) working

Comment: @thinkingmonster, sorry yes I always do a `from subprocess import...` so I forgot the subprocess. The join is basically doing what Joran's code is but using a list comprehension instead.  We join the elements separating using the newline character. We split once on whitespace and extract the first element from the split i.e `x.split(None,1)[0] `, we pass None to split on an arbitrary  amount of whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in output.splitlines():
    print line.split(" ",1)[0]
```

Im not sure what to put other than just the code ... this is something pretty basic

Comment: please provide explanation to me how can i use this to cut 5 column which has different sub-column in it